# How to catch a Qt hold event

Tags: qt, qml

How can I catch a mouse hold event in either Qt or Qt Modeling Language? I don't mean hold as in press the button and wait a certain delay before emitting a signal. I mean a user clicks a button and while its not released I want it to emit signals so that I can, for example make an object follow the mouse position while its being held down.

Comment: That works only for the first click not for the entire duration it is held down.

Comment: Have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for thanks!

Comment: There is no such continuous event as you see that. An event occurs in response to something, in your case that's mouse press. All you need are `onPress` and `onRelease`. Time between these events could be interpreted as onHold.

Comment: You maybe don't want to have a `hold`-signal, but instead a `mouseMove`-signal that you handle when `pressed` is true, e.g. by setting up a `Binding` with an appropriate `when`-expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way i solved it was using a Timer event. Each time the Timer was triggered, id check if the mouse was pressed.